# How can I add dropdown items to the column of a checkboxgriditem in google form using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is a sample code below

```
var checkboxGridItem = form.addCheckboxGridItem();
checkboxGridItem.setTitle('Where did you celebrate New Years?')
  .setRows(['New York', 'San Francisco', 'London'])
  .setColumns(['2014', '2015', '2016', '2017']);
// how do I add dropdown to all object on column 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. The [title](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-grid-item#parameters_5) field of the CheckboxGridItem Class requires a String, and a dropdown menu is related to HTML. You might be more interested in doing your own form in HTML and Javascript and deploying it as a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Comment: Thanks I have always wondered also if Google will ever let anyone extend the current classes as doing this might have been very helpful in implementing more features on Google Forms